# Need to understand angular js code mixed with jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

see the code first and code taken from this url http://jsfiddle.net/tnq86/15/

```
<div ng-app="App">
   <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
       <!-- Bind our slide model -->
       <h3>{{model}}</h3>
       <div id="slider"></div>
   </div>    
</div>

angular.module('App', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {

      $scope.model = 0;

      $scope.initSlider = function () {
          $(function () {
            // wait till load event fires so all resources are available
              $scope.$slider = $('#slider').slider({
                  slide: $scope.onSlide
              });
          });

          $scope.onSlide = function (e, ui) {
             $scope.model = ui.value;
             $scope.$digest();
          };
      };

      $scope.initSlider();
});
```

i am trying to learn angular js code. in the above code there is one controller and a controller may have many function. above controller has one function called `initSlider() and initSlider()` function has child function called `onSlide()`

just do not understand the below line

```
              $scope.$slider = $('#slider').slider({
                  slide: $scope.onSlide
              });
```

what is `$scope.$slider ?` any kind of function is trying to create called $slider ? who will call the `$slider function ?`

what is the meaning of this line slide: `$scope.onSlide ?`

see the below code too

```
$scope.onSlide = function (e, ui) {
                 $scope.model = ui.value;
                 $scope.$digest();
              };
```

how value is passing to `onSlide` function for `e and ui ?`

what is the meaning of `$scope.$digest()` line and what it does ?

how to call any function declared in controller from out side of controller.......need sample code for this.

thanks

### Paste Full code

the below code given by @charlietfl and i just paste it. thanks @charlietfl

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.6"></script>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.model = 0;
    })

    app.directive('jqSlider', function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.slider({
            slide: onSlide
          });

          function onSlide(e, ui) {
            scope.model = ui.value;
            scope.$digest();
          }
        }
      };
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <!-- Bind our slide model -->
  <h3>{{model}}</h3>
  <div id="slider" jq-slider></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *"i am trying to learn angular js code"* - you took really bad example for this. There are plenty of good resources and example, but this is is pretty bad.

Comment: It's passed by the normal browser/jQuery event system.

Comment: Rule of thumb is: jQuery should only be used inside of directives. If you're using it to select a dom element or apply a plugin inside of a controller, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a **horrible** example of using jQuery within angular.

DOM code does not belong in controllers and should be in directives.
Thus there is no reason to attach the jQuery objects, or plugin callbacks to `$scope`.

Controllers run before the view gets compiled. Angular needs the full scope in order to generate the view

The proper way to initialize a jQuery plugin is in a directive. This is the only way to be assured that the element exists when the jQuery plugin code is initialized.

`$(document).ready` is of no value within angular apps. Angular won't parse the dom until `ready` and most of the time the elements you want to target don't even exist when page first loads

Another flaw with the example is that jQuery loads after angular, and therefore angular can't use jQuery or it's plugins internally with `angular.element`

This is a more appropriate usage directive

```
app.directive('jqSlider', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // when jQuery loads before angular, `element` is a jQuery object
      element.slider({
        slide: onSlide
      });
      // function does not need to be attached to or pollute scope
      function onSlide(e, ui) {
        scope.model = ui.value;
        // scope updated outside of angular, tell angular to update view
        scope.$digest();
      }
    }
  };
});
```

View use:

```
<div jq-slider></div>
```

The reason for `$digest()` is that any events that change scope outside of angular need to notify angular to run a digest after the scope is change in order to update the view

Note that in the demo , jQuery loads before angular.js.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/vcH5iYQWyefkMPWBgNOU?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: If you down-voted my answer - I agree with it. After reading yours I would downvote myself. Still I think there is value to having it out there as oposed to deletion. I might edit for etra clarity.

Comment: what is equivalent of `$( document ).ready(function(){})` in angular js 
`$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});`

Comment: @charlietfl in my post area i paste your full code from your demo link. thanks

Comment: using directive is the equivalent. As noted in answer `ready` event is of little value in angular. @Mou makes no sense to paste my answer into your question

Comment: @charlietfl : i post your code for later reference because i am not sure the link you posted will work later or not. thanks